# Flutter Stripe Checkout: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': Cookies are disabled inside 'data:'

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, cookies, stripe-payments

### Stripe Checkout in webView flutter app

Integrating Stripe checkout with Flutter mobile app. Worked with this in previous versions of Flutter & [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin.

But now it's showing this error in the console and stuck the webView at initial URL:

```
I/chromium(26312): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Stripe.js requires 'allow-same-origin' if sandboxed.", source: https://js.stripe.com/v3/ (1)
I/chromium(26312): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': Cookies are disabled inside 'data:' URLs.", source: https://js.stripe.com/v3/ (1)
```

#### Flutter Code for Webview Stripe Checkout

```dart
class StripePaymentCheckout extends StatefulWidget {
  final String sessionId;

  const StripePaymentCheckout({Key key, this.sessionId}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _StripePaymentCheckoutState createState() => _StripePaymentCheckoutState();
}

class _StripePaymentCheckoutState extends State<StripePaymentCheckout> {
  WebViewController _webViewController;

  String get initialUrl =>
      "data:text/html;base64,${base64Encode(const Utf8Encoder().convert(kStripeHTMLPage))}";

  static const String kStripeHTMLPage = '''
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

  <head>
      <title>Stripe Checkout</title>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div style="position: absolute; text-align: center; width:100%; height:100%; top:50%;">
          <h1>Loading Stripe...!</h1>
      </div>
  </body>

  </html>
  ''';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: WebView(
          initialCookies: [
            WebViewCookie(
              name: 'sessionid',
              value: widget.sessionId,
              domain: 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/',  // <-- not sure what to do here.
            ),
          ],
          initialUrl: initialUrl,
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (webViewController) {
            _webViewController = webViewController;
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            if (url == initialUrl) {
              _redirectToStripe(widget.sessionId);
            }
          },
          navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://success.com')) {
              Navigator.of(context).pop("success");
            } else if (request.url.startsWith('https://cancel.com')) {
              Navigator.of(context).pop('cancel');
            }
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _redirectToStripe(String sessionId) async {
    final redirectToCheckoutJs = '''
    var stripe = Stripe('${dotenv.env['apiKey']}');
    
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      sessionId: '$sessionId'
    }).then(function (result) {
        result.error.message = 'Error'
    });
    ''';

    return await _webViewController
        .runJavascriptReturningResult(redirectToCheckoutJs);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're not able to enable `allow-same-origin` on the webview then you may need to force the redirect to use the full browser (outside a webview) with a redirect forwarded to a deeplink to your app for the `success_url`.

Comment: Meaning I need to open some browser app in phone but for redirection I would need deep linking to go back in app for success and cancel?
Right?

Comment: Have you found any workaround?

Comment: Yes, the backend was in php so `payment_method_types[]': ['card'],` I was missing `[ ]` here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming it was the type casting for various languages such as PHP, probably stripe is using PHP at this service so:

```dart
payment_method_types[]': ['card']
```

I was missing `[]` here

Answer (score 0):

the code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

  <head>
      <title>Stripe Checkout</title>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div style="position: absolute; text-align: center; width:100%; height:100%; top:50%;">
          <h1>Loading Stripe...!</h1>
      </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

need to be deployed on an https for your code to work.
there's a guy who presented the same problem and solved with code you can find here:

https://github.com/MarcinusX/flutter_stripe_demo/blob/master/lib/checkout/stripe_checkout_mobile.dart

and he already hosted the needed code on:

https://marcinusx.github.io/test1/index.html

Comment: It was working just fine with previous versions, I used it with 2 applications. and I asked this guy he asked me to post it on StackOverflow as he didn't had any solution at this moment

Comment: it works fine in testing mode, but in release mode it doesn't work.